# User registration form not working as it such php

Tags: php, html

I have create a form with html and php that allows a user to create an account and their information is stored within a mysql database.

The forms works and the user is able to create an account. However if the user clicks the submit button without filling in the form it seems to display that the email address has already been added.

I can't seem to see what is wrong.

My php code

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "connect.php";


if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $error = array(); // Declare An Array to store any error message

  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $address2 = $_POST['up_address2'];

  if(empty($_POST['up_first_name'])) { // if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your First Name'; // add to array "error"
  } else {
    $firstName = $_POST['up_first_name']; // else assign it to a variable
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_last_name'])) { // if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Last Name'; // add to array "error"
  } else {
    $lastName = $_POST['up_last_name']; // else assign it to a variable
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_email'])) { // if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Email'; // add to array "error"
  } else {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['up_email'])) {

      // regular expression for email validation
      $email = $_POST['up_email'];

    } else {
      $error[] = 'Your email is invalid';
    }
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_password'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password';
  } else {
    $password = $_POST['up_password'];
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_date_of_birth'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Date Of Birth';
  } else {
    $dateOfBirth = $_POST['up_date_of_birth'];
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_number'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Contact Number';
  } else {
    $number = $_POST['up_number'];
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_address'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your First Line of Your Address';
  } else {
    $address = $_POST['up_address'];
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_country'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Home Country';
  } else {
    $country = $_POST['up_country'];
  }

  if(empty($_POST['up_postcode'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Postcode';
  } else {
    $postcode = $_POST['up_postcode'];
  }

  if(empty($error)) // send to Database if there's no error
  {
    // If everything is ok...

    // Make sure the email address is avilable:
    $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email ='$email'";
    $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($con, $query_verify_email);

    if(!$result_verify_email) {
      echo 'Database Error Occured';
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email.
      $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO user (Title, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, DataOfBirth, ContactNumber, Address, Address2, Country, Postcode)VALUES ('$title', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password', '$dateOfBirth', '$number', '$address', '$address2', '$country', '$postcode')";
          
      $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($con, $query_insert_user);

      if (!$result_insert_user) {
        echo 'Query Failed ';
      }
    } else { // If it did not run OK.
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due to a system </div>';
    }
  } else { // The email address is not available.
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email address has already been registered.</div>';
  }
}
?>
```

My html form

```html
<form name="signup" id="signup" action="create_account.php" method="post">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <select name="title" id="title">
  <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
  <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
  <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
  <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
  <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="up_first_name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="up_first_name" id="up_first_name" placeholder="First Name" />
<br>

<label for="up_last_name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="up_last_name" id="up_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
<br>

<label for="up_email"> Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="up_email" id="up_email" placeholder="username@email.com" />
            <br>

            <label for="up_password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="up_password" id="up_password" placeholder="Password" />
    <br>


    <label for="up_date_of_birth">Date Of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_date_of_birth" id="up_date_of_birth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" />

            <br>


            <label for="up_number">Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_number" id="up_number" placeholder="+44 0000 000000" />

<br>


            <label for="up_address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_address" id="up_address" placeholder="Address" />
            <br>

            <label for="up_address2">Address 2 (optional)</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_address2" id="up_address2" placeholder="Address 2" />

            <br>

            <label for="up_country">Country</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_country" id="up_country" placeholder="Address 2" />

            <br>

            <label for="up_postcode">Postcode</label>
            <input type="text" name="up_postcode" id="up_postcode" placeholder="Postcode" />
            <br>

            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Register My Account" id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary"/>

  </form>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: I'm not worried about that at the moment as this isn't a real project and I'm only trying to learn as I go along

Comment: In that case, now would be a great time learn to do it the right way, then you don't get into bad habits and have to re-learn everything later on when you come to do a more serious project. And as I mentioned above, it can help with other problems as well as just security. There's simply no good reason _not_ to use parameterised queries. It isn't difficult.

Comment: Anyway I can't see any obvious reason why the code you've shown would do what you're describing. However the lack of proper indentation of the code blocks makes it very hard to follow the flow. Can you fix that please?

Comment: `if the user clicks the submit button without filling in the form it seems to display that the email address has already been added`...yes because that's what you told it to say. Now that I formatted the code for you, we can easily see that when `if(empty($error))` returns false (i.e. there are some validation errors), it goes immediately to `} else { // The email address is not available.
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email address has already been registered.</div>';
  }`...

Comment: ... That error message bears no relation to the actual situation (i.e something failed validation). You probably want to change it so it actually shows the errors collected in $error, which will then explain the problem to the user.

Comment: P.S. In the case where the email address is already being used, your code will output `You could not be registered due to a system`... which a) isn't correct, and b) isn't even a proper sentence. I think you need to look carefully at all your if/else blocks because you seem to have got a bit confused about the flow and the logic, and which output should be given in which situation. Now the code is formatted properly it'll be a lot easier for you to see what you're doing.